# Mobile web page with Clojure

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, web, clojure

I have been looking through Clojure packages to find what I need to use in order to build a mobile webpage but I have had no luck. Really what I need to happen is, if the user's device is a mobile device, I want to redirect the page to the mobile version. The mobile version should be able to provide the following functionality.

1. Detect the device and have means to obtain GPS
2. Resize page appropriately for the device
3. Handle change of orientation
4. Handle swipe gesture

I have have just started Clojure over Thanksgiving break so I am probably missing something really obvious. I have my current webpage that does nothing special for mobile but I would like to change that. Also, this is my first web page that I ever built in any language without being part of a team so I am a novice to web programming in general.

I have looked at Jquery mobile but I am not sure if this is usable with Clojure. I can't find anything on their site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Clojure or ClojureScript?  Clojure would be pure server side, generating the HTML and JavaScript (through text based generation) which is then rendered on the client side.  ClojureScript is compiled into JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Swipe, resize, and gesture are all the responsibility of the browser.

You can use the [html5 geolocation api](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) to get the location info.

Having a separate page for mobile is, in my experience, counterproductive. It is better to code the page such that it displays properly whether on mobile or desktop.

Also, in my experience, most of the changes needed to handle mobile vs. desktop browsers are better handled in the frontend, using css and javascript to adapt. Though of course you could use clojurescript to generate the javascript code. The best thing to look for regarding information on designing for multiple browsers is "responsive design". There is a lot of info if you search for it, but I am not a responsive design expert. You may want to ask a question with the javascript tag.